# E4 open a part using the eclipse way

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

This is how I open a part in my E4 application:

```
MPart part = partService.createPart("partID");
partService.showPart("partID", PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

I can also open it using Window->Open View->Other.. command. It works correctly but i noticed the part has a different behavior this way. Do you know how does eclipse handles view opening ? I'm trying to implement it the same way but can't figure how.

Comment: What do you mean by 'different behavior'? Everything uses `showPart` at the lowest level.

Comment: for instance, if I open the part in 2 different perspectives using the menu command it gets shared, like there is only one part active, that is visible in both perspectives. Also if I try to use the EModelService move() method on parts opened withing the menu it fails, because the part's parent is null (I think its being set a top level?), but it works on parts opened with my handler.

Comment: I think you use place holders (MPlaceHolder) with a shared part (in Shared Elements). But I have no experience of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've been trying all day yesterday but still couldn't figure out why it works like this. Do you know where I can find a source or some sort of documentation for how Eclipse handles view opening via menu ?

Comment: The menu is 3.x compatbility code so it will be complex. I notice Lars Vogel covers this (briefly) in his 'Eclipse Rich Client Platform' book (chapter 110).